# Why Facebook login ignore email and user_birthday in permissions?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, authentication

Is really very strange, I made some search on Google and I made some test, also using different way to login, but I had always the same result.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,user_hometown" size="large" onlogin="window.location = '/index.php';">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
</div>
<script>
    FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxx', status: true,cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
    {
        window.location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Seems that email and user_birthday was ignored: Facebook don't ask to the user the permission to give me the access to these informations.

In the example below, I receive the prompt just for authorize the hometown, if I remove the hometown, I will not receive any prompt and I will be able to access just to basic informations.

Why happen? There is a way to ask for these informations as mandatory?

I tried also with `$facebook->getLoginUrl` using the correct scope, but with the same result.

I hope that someone will be able to help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For user birthdaya and email you need extended permission from user

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,user_hometown"`

`perms` is an outdated parameter – use `scope` instead.

Comment: Thank you...changing perms to scope seems working...maybe I found an old example.